# Screen tearing on laptop's built-in display

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, screen

I have HP Pavilion (15-bc203nw with gtx1050) with fresh Ubuntu 20.04 and nvidia-440 driver installed.
I use it with external monitor and have a problem with screen tearing, but only on built-in monitor. The external one works perfectly.

I have tried adding `options nvidia_drm modeset=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia-modeset.conf`, but this solution disables my external monitor ad doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried to force composition pipeline in Nvidia settings, but I can't do it, because: "PRIME Displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings and must be configured by external RandR capable tool..."

[image: screen]

Tearing on built-in screen disappears when I switch GPU to Intel, but it disables my external monitor.

The same problem occurs on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: please try from  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf. you have to generate it.

Comment: I have tried `$ nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }`and it doesn't help.

Comment: And generating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf` disabled my built-display, so I had to remove it.

Comment: Try a lower version of the driver?

Comment: I tried multiple lower versions. None of them helped.

Comment: I have found this thread on nvidia forum (it may be helpful):
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/screen-tearing-on-hybrid-laptop/81910/5

Comment: Any luck with the problem? Same scenario here (GPU MX230 and Intel 620), have tried all drivers from 418 up to 455 and none of them can sync the PRIME display.

Comment: Unluckily not.
If you want you can ask more questions on nvidia forum mentioned above (maybe they will give you some additional tips).
The only thing I found out is preventing tearing on external monitor by closing my laptop, but it is impossible to run two displays at once without tearing. The only thing I think we can do now is keeping pinging Nvidia about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by updating nvidia drivers to `nvidia-driver-455`.

In case of Ubuntu 20.04 it should be done after updating kernel to 5.8 (You can check it by `uname -r`)

Comment: Would you set this as accepted, it will be more easier to find. Thank you for sharing.